# How do I kill Ambassador Brenner?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm in Ysa, doing the Uprising quest. I want to kill Brenner but I cannot seem to kill her. I've tried again and again to kill her, but it will not even hit her. Does anyone know what I can do to kill her?

Comment: Did you make sure to turn off the safety mode?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [wiki](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Uprising) you should 'just' be able to kill her, but it's important to disable 'safe mode'.

> Talk to Mythany Keen in the Embassy Hall in Ysa. She will ask you to
> meet her in the worship circle near the city gates after dark.
>
> When you meet Ambassador Keen, she tells you the Varani are planning
> to attack Ysa, so you should kill Ambassador Brenner, steal her
> Daggers and get rid of them.
>
> Ambassador Brenner takes a walk at the Memory Walk. Just follow the
> quest marker and kill her. Take her Daggers and AFTER talking to her,
> either salvage them at a Forge or sell them. Again the quest marker
> will guide you.  Salvaging them PRIOR to talking to her after the
> murder, will cause a quest failure. Return to Ambassador Keen and take
> your reward.
>
> You can also tell Ambassador Brenner about the plot
> against her. She will ask you to kill Ambassador Keen instead.
>
> Wait until night and assassinate her near the shrines. **You will want
> to push up on the d-pad** and sneak attack the ambassador. Take the
> daggers and take them to the location requested by Ambassador Brenner.

If you for some reason cant follow the steps mentioned on the wiki i would guess you've ran into a bug.

Your best bet would be to submit a bug ticket at [the EA helpdesk](http://help.ea.com/uk/kingdoms-of-amalur/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/).

Answer (score 1):

I could not enter aggressive mode. So I pick pocketed her on memory lane at night when she WOULD notice, the pickable items don't include the daggers, but once she yells, " thief", you can kill her, and the daggers will be on her body.